# Why do combinations with replacement result in a sample space in which outcomes are not equally likely?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, combinations

Consider the following question as an example.
A jar contains 4 marbles - 3 red and 1 white. Two marbles are drawn. What is the probability that both marbles are of the same color?

If we draw without replacement, we could find said probability by dividing the number of favorable outcomes with the total number of outcomes.
However, if we draw with replacement, we cannot do that since the outcomes are not equally likely.

Does there exist an intuitive explanation why only combinations with replacement (may) result in un-equiprobable outcomes whereas combinations without replacement, permutations with replacement and permutations without replacement always have equiprobable outcomes?

Comment: Think of a fair die.  Throwing $\{1,1\}$ is less likely than throwing $\{1,2\}$.  Indeed, the probability of throwing doubles, of any sort, is only $\frac 16$.

Comment: Worth noting:  your question depends on what you are calling your "sample space".  In my die example, i imagined that you looked at unordered outcomes from rolling a die twice.  If, instead, you look at ordered outcomes, the probability of tossing $(1,1)$ is the same as the probability of tossing $(1,2)$.

Comment: Can you explain why when drawing with replacement we can no longer divide favorable outcomes by total outcomes?

Answer (score 1):

For the first pick, there are four choices, and each is equally likely. So each has probability $\frac 14$.

Without replacement, the second pick has three choices, each equally likely, so each has probability $\frac 13$. Thus the probability for each pair of balls (where we differentiate "first ball" and "second ball") is the same: $\frac 14\times \frac 13 = \frac 1{12}$. The twelve possible arrangements are
$$\begin{array}{ccc}W,R1&W,R2&W,R3\\R1, W&R1,R2&R1,R3\\R2,W&R2,R1&R2,R3\\R3,W&R3,R1&R3, R2\end{array}$$
From which it is easy to see that half of the arrangements have two red balls, while the other half have a red ball and a white ball.

With replacement, the second pick has four choices, which again are equally likely, so each has probability $\frac 14$. Again, the probability of any pair of picks are thus $\frac 14 \times \frac 14 = \frac 1{16}$. Every possible arrangement is equally likely. Why you would think otherwise is unclear. The possible arrangements are
$$\begin{array}{cccc}W,W&W,R1&W,R2&W,R3\\R1,W&R1,R1&R1,R2&R1,R3\\R2,W&R2,R1&R2,R2&R2,R3\\R3,W&R3,R1&R3, R2&R3,R3\end{array}$$
And here we see that there are still only six combinations with a red and white ball, but ten combinations with both balls the same color - as one would expect since the four added possibilities are having the same ball for both picks, which obviously means they will be the same color.